# How to replace a function dynamically in angular 2?

Tags: angular, onclick, onclicklistener

I am working with an angular  component that has one (or more) ul element and in turn this ul element has several li elements. Each li element is represented by its own typescript component/class.

The li class has a function that handles click events something like

```
 public liClick: Function = (() => {});
  handleLiClick(event: Event) {
    this.liClick(this, event);
  }
```

I would like to override this handler to additionally change the css class of the li whenever it is clicked.

The traditional way is probably by writing another li class that extends the base one. I was wondering whether there is a simpler (possibly hackier) way to just replace the handleClick function/method with another one without changing the li class? Or perhaps there are other ways of replacing the event handler?

Comment: If `listItem` is an instance of the `ListItemComponent` class (or the appropriate class name), you could do this: `listItem.liClick = (item: ListItemComponent, event: Event) => { /* do what you want here */ };`.

Comment: He ask for overriding handleClick not liClick, but i think you can just override it. It should be private and not accessible from outside

Comment: @mr.void How would I override the handleClick while making sure that I still execute the original handleClick+extra stuff?

Comment: @JennyToy sorry i have a typo in my first comment it should be " but i think you can't just override it"

Comment: @mr.void handleClick is a public function (the class itself belongs to another module I have no control over).

Answer (score 1):

You could use property binding here, (**your.template.html**)

```
<ul>
    <li (click)="handleLiClick(event)" [class.myClass]="isTrue">one</li>
</ul>
```

(**your.component.ts**)

```
// ...
@Component({ 
    // ... 
})
export class YourComponent {
    isTrue = false;
    handleLiClick(event: Event) {
        this.liClick(this, event);
        this.isTrue = true;
    } 
}
```